# GridView Clickable

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am trying to make this gridview clickable. Everything works fine but the last cell. When I click on the last cell i.e. 8th cell, the program crashes. Any suggestion as to why it crashes will helpful.

```js
public class MainView extends Activity {
 
 ImageView back, home, site;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
     setContentView(R.layout.mainview);

        GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
        
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
            
              Intent myIntent = null;
                 if(position == 0){
                     myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), TheShow.class);
                 }
                 if(position == 1){
                     myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Exhibitor.class);
                 }
                 if(position ==2){
                     myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Visitor.class);
                 }  
                 if(position ==3){
                     myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Conference.class);
                 }  
                 if(position ==4){
                     myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ContactUs.class);
                 }
                 if(position == 5){
                  myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), VisitorReg.class);
                 }
                 if(position == 6){
                  myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ExhibitorReg.class);
                 }
                 
                 if(position == 7){
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pending", 4000).show();
                 }
                
                 startActivity(myIntent);           
             
            }
        });       
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context)
        {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            items.add(new Item("The Show", R.drawable.globecopy1));
            items.add(new Item("Exhibitor", R.drawable.workcopy1));
            items.add(new Item("Visitor", R.drawable.visitor1copy1));
            items.add(new Item("Conference", R.drawable.conferencecopy1));
            items.add(new Item("Contact Us", R.drawable.contactus1copy1));
            items.add(new Item("Visitor Registration", R.drawable.registercopy1));
            items.add(new Item("Exhibitor Registration", R.drawable.exregistercopy1));
            items.add(new Item("Delegate Registration", R.drawable.anothercopy1));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i)
        {
            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i)
        {
            return items.get(i).drawableId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
        {
            View v = view;
            ImageView picture;
            TextView name;

            if(v == null)
            {
               v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
               v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
               v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
            }

            picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
            name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

            Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

            picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
            name.setText(item.name);

            return v;
        }

        private class Item
        {
            final String name;
            final int drawableId;

            Item(String name, int drawableId)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.drawableId = drawableId;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backg" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/header" />

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#00FF0000"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >
    </GridView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#505050" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/bottom1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/bottom2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/bottom3" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: *Any suggestion as to why it crashes will helpful.* <= there is no logical explanation, programming is a magic ... you should live with this

Answer (score 3):

Your `myIntent` is `null` in the last condition. That's why crash is happening. So check if the `myIntent` is `null` before starting it. Try the following:

```
if(myIntent!=null){
   startActivity(myIntent); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in grid there is 8 items and As you said you are selecting last postion i.e. no 7 position . and you have declare `Intent` as a `null` and while checking condition you didnt set the value of your `Intent`.

```
if(position == 7)
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pending", 4000).show();
}
```

Replace above code with this

```
if(position == 7)
{
      myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), YOUR_CLASS_NAME.class);
}
```